# Adding custom tags using select2 plugin clears the select box after adding more then 1 custom option

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-select2

I am using the [select2](https://select2.org/) plugin and I have ran into an issue. When adding more then one extra tag the entire select box will be cleared. This is happening with a multiple select so I want the ability to add multiple custom tags along with the additional options.

The following is my code.

html

```
<select multiple="multiple" id="inputServices" class="multiSelect" name="services">
  <option value="SA">SA</option>
  <option value="NSW">NSW</option>
  <option value="ACT">ACT</option>
  <option value="NT">NT</option>
  <option value="QLD">QLD</option>
  <option value="WA">WA</option>
  <option value="NZ - South">NZ - South</option>
  <option value="NZ - North">NZ - North</option>
</select>
```

Javascript

```
$(".multiSelect").select2({
  tags: true,
  tokenSeparators: [',', ' '],
  width: '100%' 
});
```

Has anyone else ran into this problem? Any help would be appreciated.

Here is a [jSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/thedos/o4g25r6e/5/) so you can have a play.

Steps to recreate: (This doesn't seem to happen in the fiddle)

1. Select an option
2. Add a custom tag
3. Select another option
4. Add another custom tag

**Edit** For some reason it is only happening in the web app I am trying to implement this code into. Below is the current plugins/scripts I am using and in this order (I am loading them in the head)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script> <!--Jquery-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" /><!--Bootstrap-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script><!--Bootstrap-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/sweetalert2.min.js"></script><!--https://sweetalert2.github.io/-->
<link href="css/sweetalert2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" /><!--https://sweetalert2.github.io/-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Scripts/cropper-master/dist/cropper.css" /><!--https://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropper/--> 
<link href="css/app_1.min.css" rel="stylesheet" /><-- Googles Material Design -->
<link href="css/app_2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" /><-- Googles Material Design --></script>
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/fast-select/fastselect.standalone.js"></script>
<link href="Scripts/fast-select/fastselect.css" rel="stylesheet" />-->
<script src="Scripts/select2/select2.js"></script>
<link href="Scripts/select2/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

I have tried clearing the cache and it doesn't seem to work. Below is a series of screenshots. The first one is after selecting an option and then writing in a custom option. Then the second image is what appears when clicking the custom option (Clicking the custom option is supposed to add the option).

[image: Adding a custom option]
[image: After clicking the custom option]

**Update I have found the code that is breaking it**

```
var originalVal = this.originalVal = $.fn.val;
$.fn.val = function (value) {
    if (typeof value == 'undefined') {
        return originalVal.call(this);
    }
    else {
        return originalVal.call(this, SASWidgets.HTMLDecodeString(value));
    }
};
```

This code is used to prevent cross site scripting across the web app (It was written by my college so I am not 100% across what it does).

Comment: I've tried your fiddle adding more than 10 tags and everything seem alright. What browser are you using?

Comment: I am using chrome. Did you follow the steps  to recreate?

Comment: yes, I did exactly what you said, one option and one custom tag alternately. See [image](https://prnt.sc/k9razi)

Comment: Ok sorry I didn't realise it worked in my fiddle now. However it doesn't seem to work in the web app I am trying to integrate this code to. I will update my question and display the current plugins I am using maybe someone knows about a possible conflict.

Comment: Probably you did and it won't be usefull but... Try to clean the cache.

Comment: @Hayden Passmore, did u found any solution yet?

Comment: Hi @ershoaib, No not yet I will be working on it today though.

Comment: @Hayden Passmore, I checked out your jsfiddle yesterday i think its working good, means multiselect or adding multiple custom tag will not clear select box. change browser and try once.

Comment: I Have worked out that it has something to do with [this](https://jsfiddle.net/thedos/bkjef20t/) code that I am also loading. I haven't yet narrowed it down to the specific cause but I think that I am now on the right track.

Comment: For now I have just removed the reference to the code stated above. However this is not ideal but it is a hack that fixes it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your jsfiddle and my below solution tends to be the same.

But try once may it help you

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/css/select2.min.css" />
</head>
<body>

    <select class="form-control select2" multiple="multiple" style="width: 100%;"></select>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $('.select2').select2({
            data: ["Piano", "Flute", "Guitar", "Drums", "Photography"],
            tags: true,
            maximumSelectionLength: 10,
            tokenSeparators: [',', ' '],
            placeholder: "Select or type keywords"
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Edit 25/7/2018**
If anyone else runs into this is the problem is conflicting javaScript files specifically [this code](https://jsfiddle.net/thedos/bkjef20t/). I would suggest completely removing this code altogether or commenting out the following lines;

```
var originalVal = this.originalVal = $.fn.val;
$.fn.val = function (value) {
    if (typeof value == 'undefined') {
        return originalVal.call(this);
    }
    else {
        return originalVal.call(this, SASWidgets.HTMLDecodeString(value));
    }
};
```

This code is trying to decode the values inside the select box which is causing the conflicts.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer when I "Sandbox" your code it seems  to work fine however it doesn't seem to fix the issue with the conflicting code. for now I have just removed the additional JavaScript file reference that was braking it.

Comment: I have edited your answer and added in that the html decoding code is what is breaking the code.

Comment: @Hayden Passmore, thanks for improving my answer, and glad to hear you have get rid from your problem :)